# Backup an operating system via ssh?

Tags: linux, backup

Is it possible to make a copy of all files on a disk i.e. clone and backup the entire operating system including all directories and files via ssh? I have root access and I want to be able to restore the system in case I make a configuration mistake.

I would like to make a local copy of the installation and first try the changes in a sandboxed virtualized copy of the system which is a custom Linux.

Comment: What VMWare tool are you using, and is it free/premium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `ddrescue` and `partimage` programs. Both

- run at the command line and thus can be used via SSH
- are available in the repositories of most Linux distributions
- are FOSS
- are also available on the [SystemRescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) (a Live CD) – not important for your case here, but good to know for other cases

`partimage` can even store the backup files on a different machine via network directly, if that's needed.

---

That was for full-backup (never hurts to have). If you also want to be able to easily pick specific files. `rsync` is your friend. Again, this is available with all distributions. And "pepped up" with the proper helpers, it serves well for your purpose:

- [rsync-push-backup](https://github.com/SebKuzminsky/rsync-push-backup) can be setup for the directories you care about, and then runs daily "snapshots" – only backing up what has changed. For everything else, the "hourly snapshots" have hard-links – so you can easily pick your file-to-restore with a simple file manager or `scp` command, while not expending too much disk space.
- [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) uses a similar approach for your configuration files (in `/etc`). Instead of hourly snapshots, it only makes a backup whenever a file has been changed. But as the name suggests, this one is specific to your `/etc` directory. I mention it nevertheless as you named "configuration mistake" as something you wanted to protect against :)